# SQL Server pivot. Create grouping dynamically

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I would appreciate if you could help me with the following.
This is a de-normalized, simplified mock-up of my dataset. It shows student sessions. Each student may have 0, 1, or 2 co-students per session.
I want to go from here:

```
SessionID   StudentID   Name    LastName    CoStudent
------------------------------------------------------------------
123         112         John    Smith       Mary Henderson
123         112         John    Smith       Chris Jameson
456         571         Panos   Kotsos      NULL
510         95          Adam    Jones       Ed Stevenson
850         56          Ed      Stevenson   Adam Jones
160         401         Mary    Henderson   John Smith
160         401         Mary    Henderson   Lucy Smith
```

..to here:

```
SessionID   StudentID   Name    LastName    CoStudent1      CoStudent2      NumOfCoStudnts
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123         112         John    Smith       Mary Henderson  Chris Jameson   2
160         401         Mary    Henderson   John Smith      Lucy Smith      2
456         571         Panos   Kotsos      NULL            NULL            0
510         95          Adam    Jones       Ed Stevenson    NULL            1
850         56          Ed      Stevenson   Adam Jones      NULL            1
```

I think that this can be done using a PIVOT query. The problem is that the only way I achieved it was by hard-coding an extra column: CoStud1_2 (values 'CoStudent1', 'CoStudent2').
Can I achieve the same result without adding the extra column or at least by creating the extra column at run time?

Thanks.

Chris.

```
DECLARE @STUDENTS TABLE 
  ( 
     sessionid          INT, 
     studentid          INT, 
     NAME               VARCHAR(100), 
     lastname           VARCHAR(100), 
     costud1_2          VARCHAR(100), 
     numberofcostudents VARCHAR(100) 
  ) 
INSERT INTO @STUDENTS 
VALUES
    (123,112,'John','Smith','Mary Henderson', 'CoStudent1'),
    (123,112,'John','Smith','Chris Jameson', 'CoStudent2'),
    (456,571,'Panos','Kotsos',NULL, NULL),
    (510,95,'Adam','Jones','Ed Stevenson', 'CoStudent1'),
    (850,56,'Ed','Stevenson','Adam Jones', 'CoStudent1'),
    (160,401,'Mary','Henderson','John Smith', 'CoStudent1'),
    (160,401,'Mary','Henderson','Lucy Smith', 'CoStudent2')

SELECT *, 
       Count(costudent1) + Count(costudent2) AS NumberOfCoStudents 
FROM   (-- Query goes here 
       SELECT * 
        FROM   @STUDENTS) t 
       PIVOT (Max(costud1_2) 
             FOR numberofcostudents IN ([CoStudent1],[CoStudent2]) )p 
GROUP  BY p.sessionid, 
          p.studentid, 
          p.NAME, 
          p.lastname, 
          p.costudent1, 
          p.costudent2
```

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can use `ROW_NUMBER` to create this extra column that is required to discern between co-student 1 and 2. Then use *conditional aggregation* to get the required result:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT sessionid, studentid, name, lastname, CoStudent,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sessionid, studentid, name, lastname
                             ORDER BY CoStudent) AS rn
   FROM @STUDENTS
) 
SELECT sessionid, studentid, name, lastname, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CoStudent END) AS CoStudent1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CoStudent END) AS CoStudent2,
       COUNT(CoStudent) AS NumOfCoStudnts
FROM CTE
GROUP BY sessionid, studentid, name, lastname
```

**Note:** For a dynamic number of co-students, 1, 2, ..., n, you have to use dynamic sql.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/TTBF32364)

Comment: Thanks very much Giorgos. That's an excellent approach! The only think I've noticed is that the following line returns 1 instead of 0 even when there are no co-students in a record:
    COUNT(*) AS NumOfCoStudnts

I get the correct result when I change it to:
    COUNT(CoStudent) AS NumOfCoStudnts

Comment: @ChrisKotsiopoulos Yes, this is a good catch. `COUNT(*)` counts the number of records that belong to the group, wheres `COUNT(CoStudent)` disregards null values, and counts the number of co-students correctly.